# Medical discoveries made by Christians?

Tags: global-christianity, medication, health

Wikipedia has a List of Christian Nobel laureates, but I can't find a list of great medical discoveries made by or even medical drugs created by religious people (or by Christian people)

I am not looking for some sort of exhaustive list of minor medical discoveries and inventions. I am looking for a some sort of list of major medical discoveries, inventions, innovations, as one can not seem to be found!

I mean discoveries that are more or less on the level of these discoveries: [Timeline of medicine and medical technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_medicine_and_medical_technology).

Comment: There are billions of Christians and probably thousands of medical researchers, which would make such list far too broad for this site.

Comment: This question is not seeking an exhaustive list but rather a simplified one of Christians responsible for the discoveries mentioned.

Comment: I agree that the question needs more focus, but I think this has a good basis of a great question. Please edit it to make it less of a list question.

Comment: I tried to improve the question. I am ready to further change it, if I get more ideas about how to do that.

Comment: @curiousdannii Do you think the edit is good for reopening?

Comment: How do you determine what are the "significant" medical discoveries? Each one is significant to the people it helps. Sorry, but I just don't think this subject matter is a  appropriate one for this site.

Comment: @curiousdannii - Sorry but I think that now you are just inventing reasons for not reopening the question by playing with semantics. I replaced "significant" with "major". If the "Timeline of medicine and medical technology" makes sense by adding the most relevant discoveries on that list, then a list of such discoveries made by Christians also makes sense!

Comment: As I said at the beginning, there are thousands of medical researchers. Stack Exchange sites don't allow list questions unless they are extremely well defined and can be answer with a small finite list. This question neither asks for a finite list, nor for a well defined one, as all of us would disagree over what is "significant"/"major" enough to qualify. Wikipedia has different rules, and has no issue having very long lists.

Comment: @curiousdannii - SE has no reason for not allowing such a question. Various users can develop such partial lists that can help answer the question. The religious people's participation in developing science and technology are not insignificant at all.